# Ajax.Actionlink does not load PartialView, but simple View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have been surfing a lot and still can't figure out what is wrong with my code and why does not it work.

The code is next:

```
public ActionResult FindUser()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Which loads a PartialView, allowing to find a user by name:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Find", "User"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName);
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.UserName);
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
}
```

The Index view has an Actionlink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Find user","FindUser",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "forAjax", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
<div id="forAjax"></div>
```

I have already included in the View

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

as well as these are enabled in my config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

But it still loads my PartialView in new "window" but not below the "Find user" link. Javascript is enabled in my browser. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have included `jquery` as well and you have done this **before** including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also in your partial view you have a standard form, not an AJAX form. When you submit this form there won't be any AJAX request. If you want this form to be submitted with an AJAX request make sure you have used an `Ajax.BeginForm` in your partial instead of `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Find", "User", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "forAjax", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName);
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.UserName);
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
}
```

Another thing you should checkout is the Network and Console tabs of your javascript debugging tool that you are using in your browser. Look for javascript errors as well as possible 404 in the Network tab.

Comment: No, I wanted the form just to be shown and act it like a normal one, not an async.
But thank you ! The problem was because of these 2 scripts were not included.